# How to use Downloadfile to save an image into a specific folder

Tags: c#, webclient

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= temparray.Length - 1; counter = counter + 1)
{
    if ((counter < temparray.Length + 2) && (temparray[counter] == "><img") &&    (temparray[counter + 1] == "id='header-img'"))
    {
        string j = temparray[counter + 2];

        int startIndex = j.IndexOf('"') + 1;

        int length = j.IndexOf('"', startIndex) - startIndex;

        string jj = (j.Substring(startIndex, length));

        client.DownloadFile(jj, @"C:\image.png");
    }
}
```

I get the URL for the image which is saved as a string called `jj`, but then I'm trying to save it into any folder and not succeeding.

Comment: How is it failing?  Have you checked the value of `jj` to make sure the URL you're extracting is valid?  The code looks a bit sketchy.

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to save to that folder?

Comment: Can you post the value inside the variable 'temparray'...?

Comment: the url is valid and no i think i can save it anywhere. but i would like to do it on the desktop or My Documents. But the problem is that I dont really know how to store the image any where and currently its being  saved in the bin folder in my visual studio projects folder